VBA script started generating Runtime error 424 recently
I have a VBA script to copy a range representing a schedule in Excel spreadsheet and then email it in outlook. It was running fine and suddenly started generating a "Runtime error 424" and "Object required" error. It would open outlook, populate the various fields and then stop befor copying and pasting the range into the email body.
This is the line in the primary script that causes the error - Schedule.Range(weekRange).Copy
I cannot figure out why this is suddenly happening.
Fresh eyes please.
This is the triggering script:
Sub Email_Wk01()

    Call Email_Schedule("A3:H10", "A3", "H4")

End Sub

It calls this script:
Sub Email_Schedule _
        (weekRange As String, _
         subjectRange As String, _
         endDateRange As String)

    ' Email schedule for a given week
    ' Visual Basic command recorded 1/20/2023 and updated on 09/5/2024 by Burger King #1302
    ' Emails the managers' schedule for the specified week to appropriate staff

        Dim outlook As Object
        Dim newEmail As Object
        Dim xInspect As Object
        Dim pageEditor As Object
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim homeCell As Range
        Set homeCell = Range(subjectRange)

    MSG1 = MsgBox("Would you would like to send the Managers' Schedule for week ending " & Range(endDateRange) & "?", vbYesNo)
    
    If MSG1 = vbYes Then
    
        'Optimize Code
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        On Error Resume Next
        Set outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

        If outlook Is Nothing Then
    
            Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        
        End If

        Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

        With newEmail
            .To = "Schedule"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Range(subjectRange).Value & " Managers' schedule for week ending " & Range(endDateRange).Value
            .Body = ""
            .Display

            Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
            Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

            Schedule.Range(weekRange).Copy 

            pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
            pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
            pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
            .Display
            .Send
            
            Set pageEditor = Nothing
            Set xInspect = Nothing

            Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

        End With

        MsgBox "The schedule for week ending " & Range(endDateRange) & " has been sent."
        homeCell.Select
        Mailed.Show
        
    Else
    
        Not_mailed.Show
        homeCell.Select
        
    End If
    
End Sub


Is Schedule the codename of a worksheet?

Did someone rename your Schedule worksheet?

@BigBen "Schedule" is the name of the page of the worksheet the script is pulling from.

Worksheets("Schedule").

@Bart McEndree I believe someone did, it was originally Sheet1

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy

@BigBen - thank you, that worked. Small error that I could not see.
